# BitmapImage.PixelFormat throws DirectoryNotFoundException

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmap

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BitmapImage b = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Images/SampleImage.png", UriKind.Relative));
        //PixelFormat f = b.Format;         // throws DirectoryNotFoundException
        image.Source = b;
        PixelFormat f = b.Format;           // OK
    }
```

`PixelFormat` property throws exception, if called before the line `image.Source = b;`. But it succeeds, if called after this line. Why this happens? And want can I do, if I don't want to set this bitmap as `image.Source`, only want to work with this object in the program?

Visual Studio 2012,Windows 8, C# WPF project. Images/SampleImage.png is resource file, it is shown in the Image control.

Comment: I tried your code and not getting any exception.

Comment: I'd use "Images\\SampleImage.png" to be sure

Comment: @Nitesh Then maybe the problem is just what the exception says. There is no folder Images containing a SampleImage.png...

Comment: @GiwrgosTsopanoglou The question is edited. Image exists and successfully shown in the Image control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works

```
BitmapImage b = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/YourApplicationName;component/Images/SampleImage.png"));
PixelFormat f = b.Format;
```